# Using a set time to trigger a motor function

Tags: python, function, datetime, time

I'm making and automatic dog feeder and i want the user to be able to set a preset time and when it is that time, the device will dispense food via a motor function.

this is the code (60 Lines):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

import time

import datetime


PIN_MOTOR = 14

PIN_LIMITSENSOR = 15


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(PIN_MOTOR, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setup(PIN_LIMITSENSOR, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

GPIO.output(PIN_MOTOR, GPIO.LOW)


def doCycle():

    GPIO.output(PIN_MOTOR, GPIO.HIGH)

    while not GPIO.input(PIN_LIMITSENSOR):

        time.sleep(0.2)

    GPIO.output(PIN_MOTOR, GPIO.LOW)

    time.sleep(3)

def hour():

    return int(datetime.now().hour)


def minute():

    return int(datetime.now().minute)


option = raw_input("Would you like manual or automatic mode [manual/auto]?: ")

if option == "manual":

    while True:

        selection = str(raw_input("How big is your dog (small/medium/large/exit)?: "))

        if selection == "small":

            doCycle()

        elif selection == "medium":

            doCycle()

            doCycle()

        elif selection == "large":

            doCycle()

            doCycle()

            doCycle()

        elif selection == "exit":

            break

        else:

            print("Invalid selection")

else:
    print("Automatic mode selected.")

    schedhr = int(raw_input("Please enter the hour to schedule: "))

    schedmin = int(raw_input("Please enter the minute to schedule: "))

    iterations = 1

    selection = str(raw_input("How big is your dog (small/medium/large)?: "))

    if selection == "small":

        iterations = 1

    elif selection == "medium":

        iterations = 2

    elif selection == "large":

        iterations = 3

    print("Now scheduled to do " + str(iterations) + "cycles at "+str(schedhr)+":"+str(schedmin))

    while (hour() != schedhr) or (schedmin != minute()):

        time.sleep(1)

    for x in xrange(iterations):

        print ("Doing cycle.")

        doCycle()
```

and this is the error message:

> Automatic mode selected.
>
> Please enter the hour to schedule: 19
>
> Please enter the minute to schedule: 00
>
> How big is your dog (small/medium/large)?: small
>
> Now scheduled to do 1cycles at 19:0
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "code4.py", line 59, in
>
> ```
> while (hour() != schedhr) or (schedmin != minute()):
> ```
>
> File "code4.py", line 22, in hour
>
> ```
> return int(datetime.now().hour)
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'now'

Comment: I think you want and instead of or `while (hour() != schedhr) and (schedmin != minute()):` I presume you want to match a particular time and using or will match even if just the `schedmin` is equal to  `minute()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `datetime` module contains the identically-named class `datetime`, of which `now()` is a class method.

Therefore to call `now()` and return a datetime instance, in line 22 you need to write:

```
datetime.datetime.now().hour
```

Alternatively, if you're just calling methods from the `datetime` class, it's common to write `from datetime import datetime` instead of importing only the module name (then you needn't change line 22).